# HtmlBody of on EmailMessage does not stay as set in before insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, case, emailmessage

I'm trying to cut off email threading from EmailMessage. I try to do this in BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Original email:

> Hello Tom,
>
> We saw your complaint. We are working on it.
>
> Gigasoft Support
>
> ---
>
> From: Mark Dou 
>   Sent: Friday, November 30, 2018 10:54 AM
>   To: Gigasoft 
>   Subject: Re: Email Threading in
>   Cases
>
> Hello Gigasoft Support,
>
> Please advise me how to send emails from your software.
>
> Best regards, Mark Dou

Result email:

> Hello Tom,
>
> We saw your complaint. We are working on it.
>
> Gigasoft Support

The problem.
For some reason TextBody of an EmailMessage is processed correctly. But not HtmlBody. TextBody doesn't have all text, but HtmlBody has everything.

```
public static EmailMessage cutOffQuotedThreadV2(EmailMessage newEmailMessage) {
EmailMessage cutEmailMessage = newEmailMessage.clone(false, true, true, true);

String textDelimiterToSearch, htmlDelimiterToSearch;
for (Case_Email_Threading_Settings__mdt cetsItem : getReplyDelimiters()) {
  textDelimiterToSearch = null;
  htmlDelimiterToSearch = null;

  if (cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c != null) {
    if (cutEmailMessage.TextBody != null && cutEmailMessage.TextBody.substringBetween(cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c, cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c) != null) {
      textDelimiterToSearch = cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c + cutEmailMessage.TextBody.substringBetween(cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c, cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c) + cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c;
    }
    if (cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody != null && cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody.substringBetween(cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c, cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c) != null) {
      htmlDelimiterToSearch = cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c + cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody.substringBetween(cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c, cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c) + cetsItem.Delimiter_End__c;
    }
  } else {
    textDelimiterToSearch = cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c;
    htmlDelimiterToSearch = cetsItem.Delimiter_Begin__c;
  }

  if (cutEmailMessage.TextBody != null && textDelimiterToSearch != null && cutEmailMessage.TextBody.contains(textDelimiterToSearch)) {
    cutEmailMessage.TextBody = cutEmailMessage.TextBody.substringBefore(textDelimiterToSearch).trim();
  }
  if (cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody != null && htmlDelimiterToSearch != null && cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody.contains(htmlDelimiterToSearch)) {
    cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody = cutEmailMessage.HtmlBody.substringBefore(htmlDelimiterToSearch).trim();
  }
}

return cutEmailMessage;
}
```

What I try to do is to find some predefined text in original email which indicates that *a quoted email starts from this point*. The *getReplyDelimiters* method returns lines like "From:" or "-----Original Message-----", etc.
When I run my code in Execute Anonymous on an existing EmailMessage record which has one of these delimiters it returns me what I'm expecting.
Note. A lot of records are processed correctly. I can't figure out the difference.

Edit 1.

On each modification I have an email sent to me to check what message was updated. Also I create a backup record with original HtmlBody and TextBody. Also I surround all my code with

```
try{
}
catch(Exception e){
    sendEmailToAdmin(e);
}
```

I have no such emails.

Edit 2.

All EmailMessages WITH attached images are not processed properly. But still, even on those EmailMessages TextBody is processed correctly.

Comment: So your code works on existing records, but does not work with the same content with it's running `before insert`? Do I have that right? There are some aspects of Task and Email processing that are a bit... magic. Have you tried running it `after insert` or in a future or Queueable fired by the trigger?

Comment: My code works in before insert on EmailMessages without attached images. After insert does not work as you can't perform DML update on EmailMessage record.